# Moq: Simple way to setup property that is part of multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, moq

I have some interfaces which I'm trying to mock with the following structure (simplified):

```
interface A 
{
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
interface B : A
{
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that DateCreated is a separate property for each interface, so even though the concrete objects that I'm aware of only have one shared implementation of these shared properties, calling Mock.SetupAllProperties gives each one a separate implementation. This means they do not share values, so calling ((B)obj).DateCreated = {blah} doesn't give the desired result elsewhere when ((A)obj).DateCreated is accessed.

The only way I see to solve this in Moq is to do the following:

```
var m = new Mock<B>();
DateTime closure;
m.SetupGet(x => x.DateCreated).Returns(() => closure);
m.SetupSet(x => x.DateCreated).Callback(value => { closure = value; });
m.As<A>.SetupGet(x => x.DateCreated).Returns(() => closure);
m.As<A>.SetupSet(x => x.DateCreated).Callback(value => { closure = value; });
```

This is tedious, error prone and I need to do this for at least a dozen properties and I don't know how many more. I could probably write a generic method to do this but it seems like there must be a simpler solution. Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

(I'd love to "correct" the definitions of the interfaces, but this code in common legacy code shared throughout our organization. As this is a potentially breaking change, I can't just go around making modifications all willy-nilly.)

Edit: Just to clarify, what I want is a simple way to be able to do the equivalent of this with Moq:

```
class C : B
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Since B and A both have a property with the same name and type, that single property serves both of them. It seems like since there's a simple way to do this in actual code there should be an equally simple way to do it with Moq.

Comment: I was going to say "just use `As<>()`" but I can't get that to work myself...

Comment: It seems like a questionable idea to have a member in `B` hide a member in `A`. Since you seem to not even use the `new` keyword, you should get a compiler warning that the member `DateCreated` inside `B` hides a member inherited from `A` into `B` with the same name. If you could remove the "duplicate" member from `B`, and just use the one inherited, that would solve all your problems.

Comment: Yeah I agree, that would be the best approach. But like I said, I can't just go and change the code in our common libraries. And I just noticed that there's no warning for this, because the warning level for the project is set to zero! Argh!

Answer (score 4):

After re-reading your question (I must not be awake) I realize I missed your point entirely.  I don't see an easy way to do what you want, but if you want to live dangerously you could abuse the bug I mentioned below by setting up only the base interface's property:

```
[Test]
public void Constructor_Always_Succeeds()
{
    var mockOfB = new Mock<B>();
    var mockOfA = mockOfB.As<A>();

    mockOfA.SetupProperty(p => p.DateCreated);

    B b = mockOfB.Object;
    A a = b;
    DateTime aTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime bTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    a.DateCreated = aTime;
    Assert.That(a.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(aTime));
    Assert.That(b.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(aTime));

    b.DateCreated = bTime;
    Assert.That(a.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(bTime));
    Assert.That(b.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(bTime));
}
```

---

***This answers the question I thought was asked, not the one that was actually asked***

I was able to get this to work using `As<>()`, but with a twist.  Here's my test:

```
[Test]
public void Constructor_Always_Succeeds()
{
    var mockOfB = new Mock<B>();
    var mockOfA = mockOfB.As<A>();
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

    mockOfA.SetupGet(p => p.DateCreated).Returns(dateTime);
    mockOfB.SetupGet(p => p.DateCreated).Returns(dateTime);

    B b = mockOfB.Object;
    A a = b;
    Assert.That(b.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(dateTime));
    Assert.That(a.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(dateTime));
}
```

That test passes, and without knowing more about your actual situation should work for you.

---

*However*, while initially testing this I had the `SetupGet` calls reversed (and was thinking you wanted different return values), like this:

```
[Test]
public void Constructor_Always_Succeeds()
{
    var mockOfB = new Mock<B>();
    var mockOfA = mockOfB.As<A>();
    DateTime aTime = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime bTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    // only difference, these two lines are swapped
    mockOfB.SetupGet(p => p.DateCreated).Returns(bTime);
    mockOfA.SetupGet(p => p.DateCreated).Returns(aTime);

    B b = mockOfB.Object;
    A a = b;
    Assert.That(b.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(bTime));
    Assert.That(a.DateCreated, Is.EqualTo(aTime));
}
```

And in that case it fails at the first assertion because both calls to `DateCreated` return `aTime`.  This is because of how Moq works internally, <s>but I'd hesitate to call it a bug</s> and [there is a bug filed for it](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/131).  When the call to the property is being intercepted, the setup that matches it is found with [the following code](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/InterceptorStrategies.cs#L105):

```
localctx.Call = FluentMockContext.IsActive ? 
                (IProxyCall)null : 
                ctx.OrderedCalls.LastOrDefault(c => c.Matches(invocation));
```

In other words, "find the last setup that could be used as a match for this invocation."  Since we setup `A.DateCreated` last, it could be used as a call for either `B` or `A`'s `DateCreated` property.

Perhaps inside of [`MethodCall.Matches`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/master/Source/MethodCall.cs#L219) this situation should be handled.

Comment: In my understanding, what the OP is after is a shared implementation (ie both properties should always return the same value), unlike in your first snippet.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yep you're right, I misread the desired behavior. Updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Errr, actually after another reading I see what the OP actually wants and I don't quite answer it...

Comment: Yeah I don't really like the idea of abusing a bug like that, because who knows what will happen once it's fixed? I was looking at writing an extension method to handle this but it looks like it might be quite challenging to do without losing the type inference that simplifies the syntax.